# Why do ruby's stack trance contain non matching quotations?

Tags: ruby, jruby

Why are method names in ruby stack trace aren't quoted with matching quotations? For example: `` `eval' ``. Opens with a backtick (grave accent) and closes with single quote.

Is there a reason for this?

```
jruby-9.1.15.0 :009 > test
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)
    from (irb):9:in `<eval>'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:994:in `eval'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1292:in `loop'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1114:in `catch'
```

jRuby version 9.1.15.0 (2.3.3)

Comment: It's a way to resemble **‘eval’** using ASCII characters. TeX uses it as well, but I'm not sure if that's the origin.

Comment: [Related](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html). "Only old X Window System fonts and some old video terminals show ASCII 0x60/0x27 as left and right quotation marks, while most modern systems follow the ISO and Unicode standards instead." Useful links in the references at the end, too.

Comment: This *might* be related to Ruby's Japanese roots. Latin characters in common [CJK fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CJK_fonts) have an, er... distinctive look. [Kochi Mincho](https://ct.mob0.com/Fonts/CharacterMap/Kochi-Mincho-Character-Map.png), for example, is a CJK font historically included in many Linux distributions, and its `\`` and `'` characters look like `‘` and `’`. From what I can tell, though, its Windows counterparts MS Mincho and MS PMincho have [`\`` and `’` glyphs](https://www.dafontfree.net/data/13/m/65104/font-map-ms-mincho.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just a quirky Ruby internal, a way of formatting using a plain-ASCII equivalent of proper typographical quotes like ‘this’. The closest you can get to open/close quotes is:

```
`this'
```

It looks ugly, one character is a component of an accent, the other a vertical quote, and I think they should switch the formatting, but that's just me.